# Spring reactor to return error if the item does not exists

Tags: spring-webflux

As you see below, I am trying to add a price to a product. I want to throw an error if the product already exists. However, the below code does not throw the priceInformationAlreadyExists Exception instead it starts executing the statements outside if statement

```
   return productPresent.flatMap(isPresent -> {
        if(isPresent){
            log.info("ispresent {}", isPresent);
            Mono.error(() -> new PriceInformationAlreadyExists("Price Information not found for product" + productId));
        }
        log.info("isNotpresent {}", isPresent);
        Price price = Price.builder().productId(productId).build();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(priceRequest, price);
        return priceRepository.save(price).map(p2 -> buildPriceResponse(p2));
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing return statement.

```
return productPresent.flatMap(isPresent -> {
        if(isPresent){
            log.info("ispresent {}", isPresent);
            return Mono.error(new PriceInformationAlreadyExists("Price Information not found for product" + productId));
        }
        log.info("isNotpresent {}", isPresent);
        Price price = Price.builder().productId(productId).build();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(priceRequest, price);
        return priceRepository.save(price).map(p2 -> buildPriceResponse(p2));
    });
```